# How to make Google search show new domain instead of old domain?

Tags: redirect, dns

Recently I setup a **301** domain forwarding from `www.olddomain.com` to `www.newdomain.com`.

But Google *still* shows the **old** domain instead of the **new** one.

So I tried to use Google Search Console and change the address.
However, it seems that using a 301 redirect I cannot fetch the [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com) page.

Now I am confused:

1. Is it because I used **domain forwarding** 301 instead of 301 **redirect** so Google Search Console couldn't forward to the old page?
2. What should I do for Google to show [www.newdomain.com](http://www.newdomain.com) instead of [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com) whenever I type the keyword? ex: I type "Alexaclub"

Any help or advice will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Zed. Please try to use more formatting and wholesome sentences in the future, as that really helps to understand your problem faster :)

a 301 redirect means "Moved Permanently". In my eyes, this is no forwarding, this is just redirecting. Also, it is cached very strongly. So you would have to clear your cache thoroughly if you made a mistake or changed the configuration.

What you probably need is a cname (A-entry): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record - a cname entry to map one domain to another. Just set it up for your new domain and point it to your old one.

Comment: Hello @Manticore Thanks for your reply.
well noted for the formatting in the future :)

Meantime, for this issue actually even Google search shows www.olddomain.com whenever I type keyword however when I click the www.olddomain.com, the url will show www.newdomain.com. Just the issue is Google search shows old domain on the search engine.
In this case, should I still need to setup Cname A record?

Comment: I am not sure. The problem could also be caching as google seems to re-visit / re-index only after two weeks or so. Guess you'll have to try and wait a while for changes on google to display. Meanwhile, you could use googles tools to verify everything is setup correctly. Here are some links you should probably look into:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjHq_zmtrTvAhXa8uAKHWw0AZ4QFjABegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fwebmasters%2Fanswer%2F9370220%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AOvVaw34o5X9GTIMKAXoqS4nPqvp

Comment: and this one, too: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/301-redirects